# Is there something called "technician slope"?

Tags: meaning

Is "technician slope" just a name for a slope in skiing or is it a slope for technicians?

"I'd like to ski on the technician slope."

I saw it in a Korean book.

Comment: I imagine this is a literal translation of the Korean term for what we would call an "expert" slope. See the Wikipedia article on [Piste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste).

Comment: Seems like a bad translation maybe. A "technician's slope" could be one that a technically-sound skier would enjoy, but it's just a guess.

Comment: I think it might be a bad translation of what should be **technical slope**.  For example, ["It is a very technical slope for good skiers."](http://www.valdisole.net/en/Slope-Paradiso-Tonale/)

Answer (score 1):

There is not such phrase in English ski jargon.

We speak of Nursery slopes (short easy slopes for beginners) and then by colours: Green-Blue-Red-Black, with other regional variations.

Korean seems not to use colours but classify slopes as beginner, intermediate or advanced. This could be a mistranslation, or an error for "technical" (ie requiring good technique)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never heard them called "nursery slopes". In the USA, we call such a run the "bunny slope."